# How to make Auth::user() for another table in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When we login into laravel application we can get details of logged user through `Auth::user()`. But I want to make similar thing for another table for instance when user logs in it also stores information from `stores` table and I should be able to access it through `Auth2::store()`.

What is the process and can anyone redirect me to the solution

Comment: It seems like you are talking about 2 different things here. The first problem is that you are attempting to add another `Guard`, which is where `Auth::user()` comes from. 

The second problem is that it seems that you want to simple create a facade that gives you store information for the currently logged in user, which is not hard to do. If you could narrow down exactly what you are attempting to do, then we can better help you.

Comment: Your users typically should be connected to their store(s) via a relation, allowing you to do `Auth::user()->store`. Dual auth doesn't make much sense in most cases.

Comment: @dericcain I have two separate tables for authentication - 'admins' and 'users'. How can I get the authenticated user from 'admins' table? I have already created admin guard..

Comment: @Michel You should probably create a separate question so we do not litter this one. That will allow us to talk in more detail about your specific situation. Let me know when you create a question and I will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're interested in multi-auth?

If the user is related to a store, just do `Auth::user()->store`.

Alternatively, you can create a Facade and the method `store` that does `Auth::user()->store`.